# Truncating dates in Microsoft Azure SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database, truncate

Suppose I have a timestamp and I would like to truncate this timestamp to minutes since the Sunday of the week the timestamp was in. In Standard SQL I would do something like:

`timestamp_diff(created_at, timestamp_trunc(created_at, week), minute)`
where the `creared_at` would be the timestamp that I have and `week` would be a parameter that the truncate function would take to truncate it to the week. How would this be possible to do in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer this on the assumption that by "timestamp" you mean a datetime value. The actual timestamp datatype in Sql Server (and Azure) is a deprecated synonym of the rowversion datatype, and has nothing to do with actual dates or times.

If you are dealing with a datetime value, the following will give you the number of minutes between `@timestamp_to_truncate` and the previous Sunday at 12am:

```
declare @timestamp_to_truncate datetime = getdate()

declare @sunday datetime = cast(dateadd(day,1-DATEPART(dw, @timestamp_to_truncate),cast(@timestamp_to_truncate as date)) as datetime)

select datediff(mi,@sunday,@timestamp_to_truncate)
```